# Could not import excel file, SQLServer 2008 R2 64 bit

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am executing below written query in SQL Server Management Studio

```
SELECT * INTO XLSimportTmp_109493
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Excel 14.0;Database=E:\UploadToSQL\abcdef.xls', 'SELECT * FROM [sheet1$]')
```

I have tried Excel 12.0 too but nothing works.

Below is the error I am getting:

> OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" returned message "Could not find installable ISAM.".
>   Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)".

I am running windows server 2008 64 bit, and running SQL Server 2008 R2 64 bit on it. And I have installed AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe from http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13255, still getting above error. 
Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the 64bit ACE drivers: [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13255).

Comment: I have already installed AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe but still its not working !!